# SwiftUI - Extract specific key from JSON Reponse

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to extract a specific key from JSON. I am using the Stripe API in combination with Firebase Cloud functions.

I am printing the data using:

```
   print(success!["charges"])
```

This is the output:

```
    data =     (
                {
            amount = 4500;
            "amount_captured" = 4500;
            captured = 1;
            created = 1610732200;
            currency = gbp;
            description = "<null>";
            dispute = "<null>";
            disputed = 0;
            "failure_code" = "<null>";
            "failure_message" = "<null>";
            "fraud_details" =             {
            };
            id = "ch_1I9wE0GX6DUCOIM8aadiMKBU";
            invoice = "<null>";
            livemode = 0;
            metadata =             {
            };
            object = charge;
})
```

I can get the charges section of the response, but I need to access the `id` key within the `data` array. I just need the simple value, I don't need to save it, I just need to it to pass as a parameter.

Comment: If you set a debugger breakpoint on your print line, what does it say for the type of the object `success`?

Comment: @jn_pdx It's a [String: Any]. I've been tampering with it for a while, so I've just decided to have the cloud function respond with the id alone `charges.data[0].id`

Comment: Okay, if you have a solution, that's fine.  In the future, you could use the debugger to drill deeper in.  For example, `po success["charges"]` to find the type of "charges".  My suspicion is that you needed something like `success["charges"]["data"]["id"]`, but it could've been `success["charges"].data.id` or some variant thereof, too

Comment: @jn_pdx I tried doing that - `success["charges.data[0].id"]`, I always got a nil/empty output. Furthermore, after looking at the API/documentation, I found out I don't need to use this exact method. There's a much easier way. But I appreciate the help! Thank you.

Comment: Ok -- glad you found a solution. FYI, though, the code that you posted (`success["charges.data[0].id"]`) definitely wouldn't work, since you put the key path all in one string.  It would need to be split up